# VS Code open dialog in the current folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

While working with the VS Code I was confused that the Open dialog (`command + O`) always opens project root. Expected behaviour is to open the folder containing current file.

Is there any option to switch this behaviour?

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.13, VS Code version is 1.17.0

Answer (score 0):

I think dialog window behavior depends on the OS.

You should specify what version of vs-code and what OS you are using it on. 
For me is a Linux x64 with KDE desktop environment and the expected behavior works fine.

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.13, VS Code version is 1.17.0